# How to exit Plink used to forward a port of SQL server connection, when SQL server job is completed

Tags: sql-server, ssh, command-line, portforwarding, plink

I have setup PuTTY/Plink to connect to a remote server for loading data from the remote SQL server.

I can easily call the saved session by using the following:

> c:\plink -l myusername savedsite

I can then run a SQL Server job that loads the data.

The issue I have is, that this SQL Server job is a scheduled job that runs every x minutes.

What I notice is that running the Plink command keeps the command window open. So on the subsequent run of the job, another command window opens.

What I want to do is to issue an `exit`/`logout` command to the Plink window when the task of loading the data is complete. How do I achiever this please?

Comment: You didn't show us how you use Plink - How are you providing the commands to it? - What is "SQLSERVER job"? Is this a local job that runs Plink? That's suggested by most of your question. Though the *"I can then run a SQLSERVER job that loads the data."* rather suggests that you run the job using Plink.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  have a saved session in Putty that has all the connection settings with port forwarding and key settings, I have this sessions saved as "savedsite". This saved site requests a user name upon connecting (myusername). I call Plink from a command prompt ( as shown above in my question) - c:\plink -l myusername savedsite . Sql server job is a data warehouse load from the remote SQL database. 
What I am wanting is to open the plink connection, load the data and then close the connection .  I can open the connection and load data, but I'm not sure how to close the connection setup

Comment: You didn't answer my question. How do you *"load the data"*?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - sorry -  I have an ODBC setup on the server to localhost  (plink does the rest of the work for port forwarding etc). Once the plink connection is open i can look at all the tables on the remote SQL site and retrieve the data from there. Hope I have made myself clear..

Comment: OK, makes more sense now. So how do you control Plink? How do you start/run it? Is it some scritp/batch file?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - have a simple batch file that runs the plink command.. this leaves the command window open and the secure connection open as well.

Comment: Sorry, but that still does not give us a full picture of what you are doing. How do you then initiate the loading? Do you start the batch file and without waiting for it to finish, you start the loading process? We need [mcve].

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The data loading happens as part of a data warehouse (DW) load. I can sequence the batch file to run first and once completed, then load all the tables that I am interested in. Each time this DW schedule runs, the DW tries to run the batch job first.. but the connection remains open from the previous run. I suppose what I can do is to kill all open command windows and then run batch job again... it's not clean.. but i'd rather close the open connection once the tables have all been loaded into DW as a last step in the job/ load.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it does not looks like you will provide us enough information, so that we can give you a good answer.

So only briefly: Plink won't close for you. It cannot know when you are done.

You have to close it on your own. E.g. by:

- Starting it with a redirected input and writing `exit`/`logout` to it; or
- Remembering its process ID and killing it.

We cannot show  you how, as we do not know anything about the way you run it and options your environment allow.